# Does a coronal mass ejection change solar neutrino emission rates?

Tags: sun, neutrinos, earth

Does the [CME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_mass_ejection) and neutrinos have any relation? CME is measured by Corona graphs.. How do they measure neutrinos coming from the sun? Does any of these have effects on earth's magnetic field or atmosphere..?

Comment: I'm closing this as pseudo-scientific nonsense ( on the basis of "Earth Crust Displacement" and a suspicion that the OP is thinking about the Mayan calender roll-over).

Comment: The question still has problems insofar as there is no reason to expect a connection between coronal mass ejections and neutrino fluxes, but at least now it only addresses science.

Comment: Most of suns neutrinos are created through the fusion cycle deep inside the sun (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_neutrino). CME is completely uncorrelated. And what does increasing rate mean? 1% increasing rate in minutes/years/10^5 years? Or do you want to know if the Neutrino output increases throughout the lifetime of a star?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of neutrinos coming from the sun is entirely determined by the mean energy emitted by the sun, since to make He nuclei from protons, which is the steady state energy production net process, you need to emit net two neutrinos. The detailed mechanism is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain) , but the only thing you need to know is that it starts with protons ends with He4). This means that there are two neutrinos for every 24MeV of energy produced by the sun, regardless of any other solar events.

Comment: @CrazyBuddy: It remains the same, why does it need to be said 3 times? The neutrinos don't care about anything, they just go right through the sun.

Comment: [Rough notes on the effect of a significant *planet* on the solar neutrino flux](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31753/520).